# How to resubmit code after the commit was reverted in git with visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

I had to revert a commit.  Now that I fixed the code I would like to create a pull request with the files that I have changed plus the original files that were changed.  However only the files since the first commit are showing in the pull request.  How do I tell git to update the original files also?

I created a new branch based on the fixed branch, but it also ignores the files that were part of the original commit, even though they are correct in the new branch.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new branch starting from the last commit and do the following:

1. **Revert the revert**, that is: revert the commit that was created when reverting the change.
2. Introduce the new changes. If you already have them, you can cherry-pick those changes.
3. Now, create the pull request: These would include the revert-reverted changes and the new changes you did.

*Sidenote*: If possible, I always prefer resetting the branch rather than reverting changes, specially if I know that some day I will need to re-integrate them. Resetting the branch is a good idea if the commit to revert is the last one and it was recently pushed, so hopefully no one has downloaded it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use `squash` to combine your commits. To do so, take a look at [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). This is especially elegant if you haven't pushed the changes yet, since you can basically *undo* the two revert commits, to avoid clutter in your main repository.

Also keep in mind, you can always checkout the delta on a file and stage just the changes you need:

`git checkout <branch> -- <filename>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure for reverting a commit and making changes in a single 'revert' commit:

1. Create an example commit

   ```
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (master)>echo Text > x.txt
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (master)>git add --all
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (master)>git commit -am "A commit"
   [master 07852fa] A commit
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
    create mode 100644 x.txt
   ```
2. Create a revert commit that reverts the example commit and adds an extra change

   ```
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (master)>git checkout -b feature/with_revert
   Switched to a new branch 'feature/with_revert'
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert)>git log -n1
   commit 07852fac90b5debcfdd3ea67c282c1fee77e59e6
   Author: Tymtam
   Date:   Tue Aug 21 13:28:21 2018 +1000

       A commit
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert)>git revert --no-commit 07852fac90b5debcfdd3ea67c282c1fee77e59e6
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert|REVERTING)>git status
   On branch feature/with_revert
   You are currently reverting commit 07852fa.
     (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
     (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

           deleted:    x.txt

   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert|REVERTING)>echo Text2 > y.txt
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert|REVERTING)>git add y.txt
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert|REVERTING)>git status
   On branch feature/with_revert
   You are currently reverting commit 07852fa.
     (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
     (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

           deleted:    x.txt
           new file:   y.txt

   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert|REVERTING)>git commit
   [feature/with_revert 902e37f] Revert "A commit" + changes
    2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
    delete mode 100644 x.txt
    create mode 100644 y.txt
   /mnt/c/git/ConsoleApp1 (feature/with_revert)>git log -n2
   commit 902e37f76cabe0e144e091344e8c11ab6dd5213b
   Author: Tymek Majewski <tymek@redbacktech.com>
   Date:   Tue Aug 21 13:29:30 2018 +1000

       Revert "A commit" + changes

       This reverts commit 07852fac90b5debcfdd3ea67c282c1fee77e59e6.

   commit 07852fac90b5debcfdd3ea67c282c1fee77e59e6
   Author: TymTam
   Date:   Tue Aug 21 13:28:21 2018 +1000

       A commit
   ```